# How to create a "normal" Ubuntu user account on Ubuntu-Server 19.10

Tags: ubuntu, root

I've successfully installed Server 19.10.1, then got a desktop (Mate) going on a single Raspberry Pi 4 (4gb). I went with the 32-bit version, having heard the 64-bit is not very stable. (Please contradict me if not so.) My problem is the install created a passworded account named `ubuntu`, but this appears to be root. I didn't notice that when doing `sudo apt-get install`, I wasn't being prompted for the password, i.e., this must be root, correct? I blithely installed many packages, moved over files before I noticed this, BTW. So, I assume I really should create a "normal" Ubuntu account with `sudo` privileges? Then I should move everything in this original `/home/ubuntu` user/group-wise over to the normal account? The main reason I'm worried about this is I am a teacher and I want to set up many RPi4's, and they can't all be user `ubuntu` with automatic root privileges. What can I do at this point? BTW, here's the contents of my `/etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud...` file:

```
ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

which is no doubt why I'm not asked my password.

Comment: You have a great many unwarranted assumptions in your question.  I recommend checking out xyproblem.info and then asking a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You were probably running as user ubuntu (check with `whoami).`The line:

```
ubuntu ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

is not in the default config, it was added by whoever added `/etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud...` (probably your hosting provider). Probably they had some reason to do it. It allows user `ubuntu` to run any command on any host as any user, without asking him for his password.

*Normally* (i.e. in the default config) there is a line in `/etc/sudoers`:

```
%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

which allows users in the `sudo` group to run any command on any host as any user and group.

When you are creating new accounts, you just have to add them to the `sudo` group:

```
adduser user_name
adduser user_name sudo
```

If you want to convert the `ubuntu` user to a *"normal"* one:

1. Keep a root shell open at all times (`sudo -i` to open a root shell). If something goes wrong, you'll end up without root privileges.
2. Check whether `ubuntu` has a password and add it to the `sudo` group:

   ```
   passwd ubuntu
   adduser ubuntu sudo
   ```
3. Rename the file `/etc/sudoers/90-cloud...` to something with a `.` in it (e.g. add `.bak` to the filename).
4. Try running a command through `sudo`.

**PS**: If you edit any `sudoers` file, use `visudo` to do it (it wraps the default editor), so that syntax errors are detected when you exit `visudo`.